# Matlab urlread2 - HTTP response code: 415 for URL

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to access the betfair API using Matlab and the urlread2 function available [here](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35693-urlread2).

EDIT: I have posted this problem on Freelancer if anyone can help with it: tinyurl.../pa7sblb

The documentation for the betfair API I am following is this [getting started guide](https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Getting+Started+with+API-NG). I have successfully logged in and kept the session open using these codes: (I am getting a success response)

```
%% Login and get Token

url    = 'https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/login';
params = {'username' '******' 'password' '******'};

header1 = http_createHeader('X-Application','*****');
header2 = http_createHeader('Accept','application/json');

header = [header1, header2];

[paramString] = http_paramsToString(params)

[login,extras] = urlread2(url,'POST',paramString,header)
login = loadjson(login)
token = login.token

%% Keep Alive
disp('Keep Session Alive')
url_alive    = 'https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/keepAlive';

header1 = http_createHeader('X-Application','******');
header2 = http_createHeader('Accept','application/json');
header3 = http_createHeader('X-Authentication',token');

header_alive = [header1, header2, header3];

[keep_alive,extras] = urlread2(url_alive,'POST',[],header_alive);
keep_alive = loadjson(keep_alive);

keep_alive_status = keep_alive.status
```

My trouble starts when I am attempting to do the next step and load all available markets. I am trying to replicate this example code which is designed for Python

```
import requests
import json

endpoint = "https://api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/rest/v1.0/"

header = { 'X-Application' : 'APP_KEY_HERE', 'X-Authentication' : 'SESSION_TOKEN_HERE' ,'content-type' : 'application/json' }

json_req='{"filter":{ }}'

url = endpoint + "listEventTypes/"

response = requests.post(url, data=json_req, headers=header)
```

The code I am using for Matlab is below.

```
%% Get Markets
url = 'https://api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/rest/v1.0/listEventTypes/';

header_application = http_createHeader('X-Application','******');
header_authentication = http_createHeader('X-Authentication',token');
header_content = http_createHeader('content_type','application/json');
header_list = [header_application, header_authentication, header_content];

json_body =  savejson('','filter: {}');

[list,extras] = urlread2(url_list,'POST',json_body,header_list)
```

I am having trouble with a http response code 415. I believe that the server cannot understand my parameter since the headings I have used with success previously.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

This is the error:
    Response stream is undefined
     below is a Java Error dump (truncated):
    Error using urlread2 (line 217)
    Java exception occurred:
    java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL....

Comment: I have problems understanding your matlab code. What is `url_list`, `http_createHeader` and `savejson`?

Comment: Sorry for the code, I have sort of taught myself programming so only slowing picking up convention. 

1. url_list is a variable I have assigned to hold the website address (URL) that urlread2 is trying to access.
2. http_createHeader is a function that is used with urlread2 and was provided by that developer. Essentially it creates a structured array
3. savejson is another function I found on the internet that converts a string to json. No idea if it is needed. 

I have posted this problem on Freelancer if anyone can help with it: http://tinyurl.com/pa7sblb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your problem and it seems to be caused by two things:

1) The content type should be expressed as 'content-type' and not 'content_type'

2) The savejson-function doesn't create an adequate json-string. If you use the json-request from the Python-script it works.

This code work for me:

```
%% Get Markets
url = 'https://api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/rest/v1.0/listEventTypes/';
header_application = http_createHeader('X-Application','*********');

header_authentication = http_createHeader('X-Authentication',token');
header_content = http_createHeader('content-type','application/json');
header_list = [header_application, header_authentication, header_content];

json_body = '{"filter":{ }}';

[list,extras] = urlread2(url,'POST',json_body,header_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am so sorry I didn't see it earlier

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help:-)